# After hash password not updating in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am trying to make change password option by using ajax. Here I have tried below code in controller

```
       if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))){
            $id=$this->Auth->user('id'); 
            $changePass=$_POST['cpass'];
                $cpasss=AuthComponent::password($changePass);
                echo $cpasss;
                $up=$this->User->updateAll(
                array('User.password'=>"$cpasss"),
                array('User.id'=>"$id")
            );      
        }
```

Here hash is working fine,I have seen by firebug but the problem is here password not updating in database.If I remove

```
$cpasss=AuthComponent::password($changePass);
```

then password is updating fine but without hash.May anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `updateAll()` here. Instead just save the data using `save()` and remember to pass the primary key with the save data:-

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $changePass = $this->request->data['User']['cpass'];

    $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'password' => AuthComponent::password($changePass)
    );
    $this->User->save($data);
}
```

If you do use `updateAll()` it needs to be used with caution as it does not escape the passed fields. From [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions):-

> The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be
>   quoted manually using DboSource::value().

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to:

```
   if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))){
        $id=$this->Auth->user('id'); 
        $changePass= $this->request->data['cpass'];
            $cpasss=AuthComponent::password($changePass);

            $up=$this->User->updateAll(
            array('User.password'=> $cpasss),
            array('User.id'=> $id)
        );      
    }
```

**Changes**:

1. `$_POST[]` is not the proper way of taking form data in cakephp.
2. No need to include the variables in double quotes(`"`).